# Moderator (10k) Tools API?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, api

Is there an API available for the moderator tools and stats on the `/tools` page (close and delete votes, New Answers to Old Questions, etc.) unlocked from the "Access To Moderator Tools" privilege?

Comment: As a side note, I don't think "NATO" is a common acronym anywhere other than where you're coming from. :)

Comment: @TIPS fixed, this indeed made no sense at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard sorry, I meant New Answers to Old Questions, which is sometimes called NATO in SO chat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, and don't expect that to happen. SE wants to prevent misuse of the data and the system by making available the most used general accessible information (posts, users, comments, etc.).

There are a few parts of the API that allow writing instead of just reading, those are under more-than-regular checking. For example suggesting or making edits has a check to prevent changing too much in the post. Deletion is only possible on own posts and that can't be reversed once done using the API.

Making close vote and review queue information available through the API might encourage to create bots to robo-review, which is definitely not what we want.

Answer (score 2):

According to the (supposedly) complete documentation of the API [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs), there currently isn't an API for any of the 10k moderator tools.